# Probability for 3 of a kind

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> How many ways are there to get a three of a kind in 5 card poker?

In other words, out of 52 cards, I need to pick any 5 cards. What is the probability to get the 5 cards of form AAABC where A, B and C are distinct?

Here's my solution but I'm getting an error -

Number of ways to pick the first A card = 52, second A card = 3 and the third a card = 2.

Number of ways to pick the B card = 48

Number of ways to pick the C card = 44

Number of ways to pick 5 cards = $52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48$

Therefore the answer is

$$\frac{52 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 48 \cdot 44}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48} = \frac{44}{20825}$$

But the correct answer is $\frac{88}{4165}$.

Where's the error? What's wrong with dividing permutation of success by total permutation instead of combinations of success by total combination?

Comment: You have the probability that the first three cards you draw will be the same and the next two both different. $~$ However, the order of drawing the cards should not matter. $~$ Hence you should multiply your result by $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$, the count of permutations.

Answer (score 1):

You have the probability that the first three cards you draw will be the same and the next two both different. $~$ However, the order of drawing the cards should not matter. $~$ Hence you should multiply your result by $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$, the count of ways to select places for the three of a kind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply your result by 10 (5C3) which are the different ways to obtain three of a kind in a 5 card draw.  You are not considering the possibilities of getting three of a kind in different order.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has somewhat of a contradiction.  You state of form AAABC which would make your answer correct, but you also state 3 of a kind.  If by form you mean in the order AAABC then your answer IS correct.  If you mean BAAAC is also a winner, then you maybe shouldn't have stated the form as AAABC cuz it is misleading since form means arrangement.